# When I render the model it appears without the subdivision surface modifier

Tags: rendering, subdivision-surface

[image]When I apply subdivision surface modifier for a model I set render and view to 3 then I apply it but when I render the model it appears without the subdivision surface modifier as if it is set to 1 what should I do?

I tried to render it as a video or as a photo I do not see the modifier applied.

Comment: Check did you set simplify?

Comment: is the camera icon enabled on the modifier? please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your post and add an image to the question that shows the settings you are using for the modifier.

Comment: All caps is considered yelling. There is no need for that. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry for th caps I didn't mean it @cegaton

Comment: @Crantisz what is simplify?

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply subdivision surface.Dont leave it click apply and then you can render video or image with sub surface. [image]

Comment: Hi. Please take screenhots of your screen instead of photos. They will be higher quality. https://www.take-a-screenshot.org